# Как правильно спарсить разрешение видео регулярными выражениями?

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

надо чтобы вытаскивал из примера 1280x718 и из второго примера 720x304

```
string primer = "Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x718 [SAR 1:1 DAR 640:359], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 2k tbc (default)"

string primer2 = "Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (Advanced Simple Profile) (XVID / 0x44495658), yuv420p, 720x304 [SAR 1:1 DAR 45:19], 1520 kb/s, 23.98 tbr, 23.98 tbn, 23.98 tbc"
```

Comment: `\b\d+x\d+\b`?

А если серьёзно, вы хотите, чтобы мы на основе двух примеров восстановили грамматику?

Comment: \b\d+x\d+\b попадает еще 0x44495658
\b\d{3,}x\d{3,}\b в принципе подходит, спасибо)

Answer (score 2):

*Ответ из комментариев*

```
\b\d+x\d+\b
```